# Do the fractional electric charges in FQHE violate the Dirac quantization relation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topology, strong-correlated

Dirac quantization relation says that the electric charge must be quantized if there is a magnetic monopole in our universe. But the fractional quasi-particles and quasi-holes in FQHE have fractional charge, while I haven't seen any argument on their contradiction with Dirac quantization, so do they violate this relation?  Intuitively, I suppose no but I do not find a proper argument. I know that for a deconfined quark with e/3 electric charge, one can say that they gain an extra phase from the SU(3) gauge group when the monopole also carries a color magnetic charge, then by summing the contribution together we get the correct answer. But there seems no other gauge group here for FQHE, so is it the topological degeneracy that plays the role? Or will the monopole need to be put outside the FQHE material, and the boundary state will cancel the fractional phase?

Comment: FQHE is a $2+1$ theory, Dirac quantization holds in $3+1$. 2) The fractional "particles" in the FQHE are line operators, not point operators. There is no Dirac quantization condition for lines, only points.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks. I agree with your first point but I'm now confused with what will happen if we insert a $2\pi$ flux. I know that a quasi-particle with $e/q$ will be transported to the other side for $\nu=1/n$ FQH state, but is the state the same state as the one before flux inserting, or become a state degenerate with the original one?

Comment: Besides, could you explain a bit more concretely or provide some reference for why "particles" are line operators? I briefly know about wavefunctions arguments like Laughlin wavefunctions and the CS field theory for FQH, but I could not figure out what your line operators mean.